# Autosys JIL Ice, update, start

Tags: autosys

I have a job that runs every 5 minutes and takes a few minutes to run.

I just want to do a simple update to it. (change the log location).  But when I run my update command it fails because it's hard to get the job when it's not busy running.

I could put it on ice, then update it, and start it back up.  Is there a way to do that in one JIL script?

I'm thinking:

```
updatejob: JOB_NAME 
status: on_ice
updateJob: JOB_NAME
std_out_file: THE_PATH
updatejob: JOB_NAME
status: active (? not sure the command there)
```

Would that work in one script? Or do I need to issue commands to set the job status to ice?